# preg_replace backreference date function

Tags: php, regex, function, preg-replace, backreference

PHP 5.2.15

I am trying to replace {date[F]} with the date function.

I have the pattern which works great.

```
preg_replace('/({date\[(.*?)\]})/', date(${2}), $subject);
```

I have tried preg_replace_callback but it doesn't seem to work even when I use create_function()

I get mostly undefined errors on my methods tried.

Comment: You should use `([^]]+)`, not `(.*?)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do need the [`/e` modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php). And the replacement expression must be a string:

```
= preg_replace('/(\{date\[(.*?)\]})/e', 'date("$2")', $subject);
```

Note that you also forgot to escape the first `{` curly brace.

See the manual examples for [`preg_replace`#105490](http://php.net/preg_replace#105490). Or how [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback) callbacks must unpack the match parameter (which sounds like your original issue).

Comment: Sweet, it is working although I am getting some strict standard errors using preg_replace('/(\{date\[([^]]+)\]})/e', 'date("$2")', $subject);